# What determines the rise time of a digital signal?

Tags: digital-logic, rise-time

What are the factors that determine or affect the rise time of a digital signal?

Answer (score 0):

The load capacitance and the driver strength. In extreme cases it also depends on the rise time of the input signal.

Driver strength can depend on the power supply voltage. It also strongly depends on temperature.

Comment: Driver strength?

Comment: As in how much current the driver can supply. Eg a 40mA driver will be able to charge/discharge a given capacitance faster than a 2mA driver.